# Is it possible to host a new smartcontract and access it through api?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Smart contract is already deployed and we can view our own smart contract. Now we want to access its method from API?

```
var tokenContractABI = {your token contract ABI}
var tokenContractAddress = "{your token contract address}"
var tokenContract = eth.contract(tokenContractABI).at(tokenContractAddress)
tokenContract.testMethod()
```

like at this link https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC, Its mentioned that apis are available for default contract and can be accessed from api (localhost:8545) using `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getCode","params":["0xa94f5374fce5edbc8e2a8697c15331677e6ebf0b", "0x2"],"id":1}`

If i want to use my smart contract method to be exposed to API, then how can i use them. can i do it like this ? `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"tokenContract_testMethod","params":["", "0x2"],"id":1}`

PS: My understanding is admin, personal, eth are default contracts deployed when we start blockchain.? Am i correct ? please validate this point also.

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 2):

You don't "host" a smart contract. Contracts are deployed to the blockchain so everyone participating on the network has a copy of it.

JSON-RPC has a "data" field that contains all of the information regarding the contract method you are wanting to call (name, inputs, outputs) that is encoded via [ABI](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI).